# DrMemory and Delphi, no line numbers

Tags: delphi, debugging, dr-memory

I just found out about DrMemory, which seems like an amazing debugging tool, if somewhat complex at first glance.

When I run it under Delphi with all debug options I can find, it stills says it cannot find line numbers and instead displays hex offsets into the executable.

Is there a way to have Delphi 10+ generate what DrMemory needs to provide line numbers?

Here's a link to DrMemory: http://www.drmemory.org/

Thanks!

Comment: What debug info does it need. I'd expect it wants pdb. Which delphi cannot produce. They are some tools out there that can generate pdb from Delphi debug output but they are patchy at best.

Comment: Contact the project folks at DrMemory and ask what kind of debugging info it expects, and then come back here and ask a specific question about whether or not the Delphi linker can produce that info.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote the team and will see what they say,